# GPU AMD firePro W5130m not working in elementary OS

Tags: drivers, graphics, amd-graphics

can't setup the AMD firePro W5130m GPU on my laptop. the Linux in AMD is too old 2015 and it gives :

=====================================================================

AMD Proprietary Driver Installer/Packager

=====================================================================

error: Detected X Server version 'XServer _64a' is not supported. Supported versions are X.Org 6.9 or later, up to XServer 1.10 (default:v2:x86_64:lib:XServer _64a:none:4.15.0-36-generic:) Installation will not proceed.

but when use `sudo lshw -C display` it showes completly differnet GPU.

how to install AMD firePro W5130m ?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your card should be handled by the open source AMD driver, without needing anything to install. The closed one you are trying to install is obsolete.
You can check whether things are working fine by using the command `glxinfo|grep OpenGL`. It should tell you the Mesa version, OpenGL version and some info about the graphics card.
The model number you see is probably the real chip on the card, without the fancy name.

Comment: OpenGL vendor string: Intel Open Source Technology Center
OpenGL renderer string: Mesa DRI Intel(R) HD Graphics 530 (Skylake GT2) 
OpenGL core profile version string: 4.5 (Core Profile) Mesa 19.0.8
OpenGL core profile shading language version string: 4.50
OpenGL core profile context flags: (none)
OpenGL core profile profile mask: core profile
OpenGL core profile extensions:
OpenGL version string: 3.0 Mesa 19.0.8
OpenGL shading language version string: 1.30
OpenGL context flags: (none)
OpenGL extensions:

Comment: No AMD or its card property is mention?

Comment: This is the Intel one. Now try the command `DRI_PRIME=1 glxinfo|grep OpenGL`. This will change to your second graphics card. Default (0) is the Intel.

Comment: there is any way that can i make AMD is Default ?

Comment: penGL vendor string: X.Org
OpenGL renderer string: AMD VERDE (DRM 2.50.0, 4.15.0-36-generic, LLVM 8.0.0)
OpenGL core profile version string: 4.5 (Core Profile) Mesa 19.0.8
OpenGL core profile shading language version string: 4.50
OpenGL core profile context flags: (none)
OpenGL core profile profile mask: core profile
OpenGL core profile extensions:
OpenGL version string: 4.5 (Compatibility Profile) Mesa 19.0.8
OpenGL shading language version string: 4.50
OpenGL context flags: (none)
OpenGL profile mask: compatibility profile

Comment: You can use it permanently but that will generate more heat and the accumulator will lose power faster on a notebook. Thus it is recommended to use it through DRI_PRIME=1, only for the program that truly needs it. The tutorial about permament switch can be found [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HybridGraphics).